# ehcp - access pop3 account

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, pop3, courier

I finally manage to get mail working with ehcp on an ubuntu server. I can get and send email from the webmail, but I can't seems to be able to access the pop3. I can telnet to the pop3 (server?) but my identification are rejected.

Apparently the pop3 server is courier which seems to be configured like it should.

Someone has any idea about this ?

Thank you

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

While trying to login to pop3, try this

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

You will see problems and error messages there, which will help you debug problems.

Most probably, your POP3 server is not installed (normally, it should be installed with  ehcp) or is misconfigured somehow.

You may find more info about this on the www.ehcp.net site, or more specifically [here](http://www.ehcp.net/?q=node/622).